# AutoML NL - Training model based on ICD10-CM - Amount of text required

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, icd

We are currently working on integrating ICD10-CM for our medical company, to be used for patient diagnosis. ICD10-CM is a coding system for diagnoses.

I tried to import ICD10-CM data in description-code pairs but obviously, it didn't work since AutoML needed more text for that code(label). I found a dataset on Kaggle but it only contained hrefs to an ICD10 website. I did find out that the website contains multiple texts and descriptions associated with codes that can be used to train our desired model.

Kaggle Dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/shamssam/icd10datacom

Sample of a page from ICD10data.com:
https://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/A00-B99/A15-A19/A17-/A17.0

Most notable fields are:
- Approximate Synonyms
- Clinical Information
- Diagnosis Index

If I made a dataset from the sentences found in these pages and assigned them to their code(labels), will it be enough for AutoML dataset training? since each label will have 2 or more texts finally instead of just one, but definitely still a lot less than a 100 for each code unlike those in demos/tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see [here](https://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes), the disease code has a tree-like structure where, for instance, all L00-L99 codes refer to "Diseases of the skin and subcutaneous tissue". At the same time L00-L08 codes refer to "Infections of the skin and subcutaneous tissue", and so on.

What I mean is that the problem is not 90000 examples for 90000 different independent labels, but a decision tree (you take several decisions in function of the previous decision: the first step would be choosing which of the about 15 most general categories fits best, then choosing which of the subcategories etc.)

In this sense, probably autoML is not the best product, given that you cannot implement a specially designed decision tree model that takes into account all of this.

Another way of using autoML would be training separately for each of the decisions and then combine the different models. This would easily work for the first layer of decision but would be exponentially time consuming (the number of models to train in order to be able to predict more accurately grows exponentially with the level of accuracy, by accurate I mean afirminng it is L00-L08 instad of L00-L99).

I hope this helps you understand better the problem and the different approaches you can give to it!